# Extract information from nested dictionary (google maps distance_matrix)

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3

How do I get only the "distance" and "duration" from this nested dictionary to only include the values: 6.1 km and 21 mins? I tried the .get function but I get a "0" output.

```
my_distance = gmaps.distance_matrix('Empire State','10031')

my_distance

{'destination_addresses': ['New York, NY 10026, USA'], 'origin_addresses': ['Manhattan, NY 10036, USA'], 'rows': [{'elements': [{'distance': {'text': '6.1 km', 'value': 6138}, 'duration': {'text': '21 mins', 'value': 1257}, 'status': 'OK'}]}], 'status': 'OK'}
{'destination_addresses': ['New York, NY 10031, USA'], 'origin_addresses': ['Manhattan, NY 10036, USA'], 'rows': [{'elements': [{'distance': {'text': '10.3 km', 'value': 10314}, 'duration': {'text': '20 mins', 'value': 1176}, 'status': 'OK'}]}], 'status': 'OK'}
{'destination_addresses': ['New York, NY 10032, USA'], 'origin_addresses': ['Manhattan, NY 10036, USA'], 'rows': [{'elements': [{'distance': {'text': '12.0 km', 'value': 12015}, 'duration': {'text': '17 mins', 'value': 1034}, 'status': 'OK'}]}], 'status': 'OK'}


my_distance
test=my_distance.get('distance',0)
test

0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to index the dictionary multiple times to get these values, as they are nested multiple layers in. For example, to get the distance, use:

```py
my_distance["rows"][0]["elements"][0]["distance"]["text"]
```

Here is the full code to get both values:

```py
my_distance = {'destination_addresses': ['New York, NY 10026, USA'], 'origin_addresses': ['Manhattan, NY 10036, USA'], 'rows': [{'elements': [{'distance': {'text': '6.1 km', 'value': 6138}, 'duration': {'text': '21 mins', 'value': 1257}, 'status': 'OK'}]}], 'status': 'OK'}

values = ["distance", "duration"]

results = []
for v in values:
    results.append(my_distance["rows"][0]["elements"][0][v]["text"])

for v, r in zip(values, results):
    print(f"{v}: {r}")
```

This prints:

```
distance: 6.1 km
duration: 21 mins
```